# I want to get each array values separately for calculation

Tags: java, arrays

I'm java beginner, This is my code.

```
int [] arr = {1,3,4,5,5,6};
```

I want to get each array values separately for calculation. can you please help me.

For example: I want first two digits (array index 0 and 1) only how to get that.

Comment: You mean `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`?

Comment: for seperate calculation you can use arr[index]. where index is index value of particular value.

Comment: for example: I want to multiply first two digit (1*3) after that (4*5) like that.. so i want to get these values separately.

Comment: @user9437598 i just provided an example for that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return a specific element of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376735/how-to-return-a-specific-element-of-an-array)

Answer (score 3):

to get the first and second item, do like this:

```
int [] arr = {1,3,4,5,5,6};

System.out.println("pos 0: "+arr[0]+" pos 1: "+arr[1]);
```

by doing arr[n-1], you select the 'n'th value in the array.

now, if you want to multiply these first two values..:

```
int result = arr[0] * arr[1]; // 1 * 3 
System.out.println(result) // 3
```

Comment: And in addition: arrays start to count with 0 - so if there are 5 elements in the array, they are "numbered" with index 0,1,2,3,4.

Answer (score 1):

> For example: I want to multiply first two digit (1*3) after that (4*5) like that.. so I want to get these values separately.

To do this,

```
int [] arr = {1,3,4,5,5,6};
int ans;

for(int i=0;i<6;i+=2){
    ans = arr[i]*arr[i+1];
    System.out.println(""+ans);
}
```